# "Collection corresponding..." error on Swift 3 upgrade

Tags: swift, swift3, xcode8

Here's a pre-Xcode-8 Swift call ..

```
func gappizeAtDoubleNewlines()
    {
    let t = self.text!
    var index = t.startIndex
    var follow = index.advancedBy(1)

    for i in 0 ..< (t.characters.count-4)
        {
        let r = index ... follow
        if ( t.substringWithRange(r) == "\n\n" )
            { alterLineGapHere(i) }

        index = index.advancedBy(1)
        follow = index.advancedBy(1)
        }
    }
```

using the automatic upgrade to Swift3, I got these errors...

[image]

in text,

```
func gappizeAtDoubleNewlines()
    {
    let t = self.text!
    var index = t.startIndex
    var follow = <#T##Collection corresponding to `index`##Collection#>.index(index, offsetBy: 1)

    for i in 0 ..< (t.characters.count-4)
        {
        let r = index ... follow
        if ( t.substring(with: r) == "\n\n" )
            { alterLineGapHere(i) }

        index = <#T##Collection corresponding to `index`##Collection#>.index(index, offsetBy: 1)
        follow = <#T##Collection corresponding to `index`##Collection#>.index(index, offsetBy: 1)
        }
    }
```

What is the solution in Swift3 ??

Comment: @Hamish - thanks a million for that.

Comment: Sure thing – I have a habit of accidently answering questions in the comments :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [SE-0065: 'Collections move their indices'](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0065-collections-move-indices.md) – in this case you can just replace the editor placeholders with `t`:

```
func gappizeAtDoubleNewlines() {

    let t = self.text!
    var index = t.startIndex

    // Note that because substring(by:) takes a Range<String.Index>, rather than
    // a ClosedRange, we have to offset the upper bound by one more.
    var follow = t.index(index, offsetBy: 2)

    for i in 0 ..< (t.characters.count-4) {
        let r = index ..< follow
        if (t.substring(with: r) == "\n\n") {
            alterLineGapHere(i)
        }

        index = t.index(index, offsetBy: 1)
        follow = t.index(follow, offsetBy: 1)
    }
}
```

Although note that `String` isn't a `Collection` itself, it just implements some convenience methods for indexing that forward to `t.characters`, which *is* a `Collection`.

Comment: and for anyone googling, with the very latest Swift, I found this extension handy ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/39677704/294884